# How to cause validation when clicking on a ToolStripButton Menu from a MDI in Windows Form Application?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a ContextMenuStrip with a ToolStripButtonMenu "Print".
A MDI child form is open containing a DataGridView. I am doing a validation to an editable column "Copies" in that grid. I don't want the user to input letters for example. The validation is working fine when leaving the cell but if I am clicking on a control such as the "Print" button, the validation is not caused.

The following screen shot shows how I can click on the "Print" button while the Copies cell contains letters:

[image]

```
// The code for the cell validation
private void QuantitiesDataGridView_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == QuantitiesDataGridView.Columns[COL_COPIES].Index)
        {
            QuantitiesDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "";
            int enteredValue;

            if (!int.TryParse(e.FormattedValue.ToString(), out enteredValue) || enteredValue < 1)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                QuantitiesDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "Invalid number of copies";
            }
        }
    }
```

I was looking for a property of the ToolStripButtonMenu such as CauseValidation but there is not such one.

Is there a way to trigger the validation when clicking on one of the ToolStripButtonMenu so the Print button will not be triggered until the Copies value is valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ToolStripButton's Click method, try calling the active form's ValidateChildren function:

```
private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (this.ActiveMdiChild.ValidateChildren()) {
    // do your processing ...
  }
}
```